# Subversion deleted a folder in working copy that was not under version control on a merge

Tags: svn

Situation :
One site is a working copy of a branch .
I update this site from the trunk  with svn merge.

Site (working copy of branch) directory structure is:
files/
files/images/
files/audio/

On the trunk there is no files/audio subfolder.

I accidentally committed a change in files/ in my local development working copy to the trunk.
I merged on the working copy on my server from the trunk,
and files/audio disappeared, although it was not under version control.

I suppose since files/ is under version control but files/audio/ is not ,
svn merge , merged the files/ directory and since it did not find 
an audio subfolder on the trunk , it deleted it from the working copy.
I remember that this folder was sometime under version control but sometime I set it to svn:ignored.

Any ideas of how I can get my folder back?

Thanks.

(ps. svn sucks)

Comment: svn won't do like you supposed expect you deleted an audio dir under version control before

Comment: Subversion won't touch unversioned files or directories. You get a conflict if an operation expected to see a versioned file in its place.

Comment: BTW: I would recommend removing comments like 'svn sucks' as that makes it less likely that somebody will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will be able to recover the files is to use the same tools you would use if you had deleted any other file from your disk.